# Bootstrap 3 Full-width Jumbotron outside container after <header>

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Starting out with Bootstrap 3 and just getting used to it.

I've copied the navbar from the Bootstrap 3 docs becuase it has the exact functionality that I want and why invent the wheel hey.

I want to put a **Jumbotron** after the header but I want it to be full width, so according to the docs I don't enclose it in a **container** div.

The problem is that when I omit the container div it slides back under the header but I want it to start where the header ends. If I put it inside a container it sits nicely under it.

Can someone show me where I'm going wrong and how to fix it without making some hack div that pushes it down. Many thanks.

I want to keep the container in the header tag becuase I don't want these elements stretching to the sides.

```
<!-- Docs master nav -->
<header class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top bs-docs-nav" role="banner">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button class="navbar-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".bs-navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a href="../" class="navbar-brand"><img src="imagenes/logo.png" /></a>
    </div>
    <nav class="collapse navbar-collapse bs-navbar-collapse" role="navigation">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right pull-down">
        <li class="">
          <a href="#">Menu</a>
        </li>
        <li class="">
          <a href="#">Galería</a>
        </li>
        <li class="">
          <a href="#">Calendario</a>
        </li>
        <li class="">
          <a href="#">BH Musicos / Talentos</a>
        </li>
        <li class="">
          <a href="#">Blog</a>
        </li>
        <li class="">
          <a href="#">Contacto</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
<div class="jumbotron">
  <h1>Hello World</h1>
  <p>Testing one two three</p>
</div>
```

Comment: just a note, the `bs-docs-nav` class is not required

Comment: @koala_dev, what does the `bs-docs-nav` class do?

Comment: @ayjay `.bs-docs-nav` is not part of Bootstrap, it is used only in the documentation to add some custom styles

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you look at the "Fixed to top" section on the [navbar docs](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar), there's an alert urging you to add padding to the body:

> **Body padding required**
>
> The fixed navbar will overlay your other content, unless you add
>   `padding` to the top of the `<body>`. Try out your own values or use our
>   snippet below. Tip: By default, the navbar is 50px high.
>
> `body { padding-top: 70px; }`
>
> Make sure to include this after the core
>   Bootstrap CSS.

Comment: Is there something that can be added to the body to make it more responsive in bootstrap, i.e. that when the viewport is reduced an the header becomes larger in height the below content go down as well?

Comment: @AdamBrown I'm not sure that there is, I can only think of a javascript solution to listen to the window resize event and adjust the padding based on the header height

Comment: @AdamBrown actually you can also set up a media query at the point where the menu starts overflowing to a new line and increment the padding there

Answer (score 0):

Adding a container inside the jumbotron will also fix this.